# Проблема с Custom Alert

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

[image: рис.1]

[image: рис.2]

Рис. 1 получается вместо рис. 2, сначала на симуляторе проблема была, на устройствах все норм было, а теперь и на устройствах, кто подскажет в чем дело? причем xcode нечего не пишет, типо все так и должно!

```
 - (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {

    NSArray *array_btn = @[@"Камера", @"Галерея", @"Отмена"];

    MPAlertTableView *alert = [[MPAlertTableView alloc] initWithCaller:self title:@"Самоучитель Selfie"
                                                               message:@"Создайте новую или выберите фотографию"
                                                          buttonTitles:array_btn];

    [alert showInView:self.view];  
}
```

Скину весь код на случай а вдруг реально где заметный косяк?
Код MPAlertTableView

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice         currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#import "MPAlertTableView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define MAX_ALERT_HEIGHT (260.0)
#define MAX_ALERT_MESSAGE_HEIGHT (200.0)
#define BTN_TAG_BASE     (0x1000)

#define BTN_1ST_X        (14.0)
#define BTN_GAP          (5.0)

#define MY_TITLE_LABEL_H (52.0)
//#define MY_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT (36.0)

 @interface MPAlertTableView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    //    id delegate;
    UIView *_alertViewWithTable;
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    NSArray *data;
 }
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MPAlertTableViewDelegate> caller;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray             *data;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *tableSelectedRowIndexs;
@end

@implementation MPAlertTableView

@synthesize  selectionType;
@synthesize  caller, data;
@synthesize  tableSelectedRowIndexs;
//@synthesize  mp_tableView;
//@synthesize  mp_buttons;
//@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
self.data = nil;
self.caller = nil;
    }

- (id) initWithCaller:(id<MPAlertTableViewDelegate>)_caller title:    (NSString*)_title message:(NSString *)_messageString
      tableDataSource:(NSArray*)_tableDataArray tableSelectedRowIndexs:    (NSArray*)_tableSelectedRowIndexs buttonTitles:(NSArray*)buttonTitles
 {
     CGRect frame;
     UIInterfaceOrientation orient = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]      statusBarOrientation];
     if (orient == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orient ==      UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
         NSLog(@"Device has lang.");
        //int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
         NSLog(@"%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

         if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
             frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]      bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
          NSLog(@"8.0 eche.");
         }

         else {

             frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]      bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);}

          }
     else{
    frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
NSLog(@"Device has portret.");}

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if(!self)
    return self;

self.caller         = _caller;
self.data           = _tableDataArray;
self.tableSelectedRowIndexs    = nil;
self.selectionType  = ATV_SELECTION_TYPE_SINGLE; // default

int data_cnt = 0x00;
if(_tableDataArray) data_cnt = (int)[_tableDataArray count];

if(data_cnt > 0)
{
    self.tableSelectedRowIndexs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(int idx=0x00; idx<data_cnt; idx++)
    {
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idx];
        [tableSelectedRowIndexs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE] forKey:num];
    }

    if(_tableSelectedRowIndexs)
    {   // _selIdxs가 있으면 배열의 값을 설정함.
        for(id num in _tableSelectedRowIndexs)
        {
            NSNumber *insert_num = nil;
            int sel_idx;
            if([num isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            {
                sel_idx    = [num intValue];
                insert_num = num;
            }
            else if([num isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                sel_idx = [((NSString *)num) intValue];
                insert_num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sel_idx];
            }
            else
                sel_idx = -1;

            if(insert_num && (sel_idx >= 0x00) && (sel_idx < data_cnt))
                [tableSelectedRowIndexs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:insert_num];
        }
    }
}

self.alpha = 0.95;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.6];
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

UIImage *_alertBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert22.png"];

if ([_alertBg respondsToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:)])
    _alertBg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"alert22.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0)];
else
    _alertBg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"alert22.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 25 topCapHeight: 40];


UIImage     *_cancelBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_btn3.png"];
UIImageView *_alertImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_alertBg];

float alert_width = _alertImgView.frame.size.width;
float alert_height = 5.0;

//add text
UILabel *_titleLbl = nil;
//UIScrollView *_msgScrollView;

// title
if (_title)
{
    _titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, alert_height, alert_width-20.0, MY_TITLE_LABEL_H)];
    _titleLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    _titleLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    _titleLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    _titleLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:25];
    _titleLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _titleLbl.minimumScaleFactor = 12.0;
    _titleLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _titleLbl.text = _title;

    alert_height += _titleLbl.frame.size.height + 5.0;
}
else
{
    alert_height += 15.0;
}

UIScrollView *_msgScrollView = nil;
UITableView  *_tableView = nil;
if(data_cnt)
{
    float max_table_height = MAX_ALERT_HEIGHT - alert_height - _cancelBtnImg.size.height;
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, alert_height, alert_width-20.0, max_table_height)];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

    alert_height += _tableView.frame.size.height + 5.0; // 15.0;
}
else
{
    if (_messageString)
    {
        float max_message_height = MAX_ALERT_MESSAGE_HEIGHT - alert_height - _cancelBtnImg.size.height;

        UILabel *_messageLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, 0.0)];
        _messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
        _messageLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:20];
        _messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _messageLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _messageLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _messageLbl.text = _messageString;

        [_messageLbl sizeToFit];
        _messageLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, _messageLbl.frame.size.height);

        while (_messageLbl.frame.size.height>max_message_height && _messageLbl.font.pointSize>12)
        {
            _messageLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:_messageLbl.font.pointSize-1];
            [_messageLbl sizeToFit];
            _messageLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, alert_width-40.0, _messageLbl.frame.size.height);
        }

        _msgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, alert_height, alert_width-20.0, (_messageLbl.frame.size.height>max_message_height)?max_message_height:_messageLbl.frame.size.height)];
        _msgScrollView.contentSize = _messageLbl.frame.size;
        [_msgScrollView addSubview:_messageLbl];

        alert_height += _msgScrollView.frame.size.height + 10.0; // 15.0;
    }
    else
    {
        alert_height += 15.0;
    }
}

//add buttons
NSMutableArray *btn_array  = [NSMutableArray array];
if(buttonTitles)
{
    int btn_count = (int)[buttonTitles count];
    float x_displ = (int)((alert_width-_cancelBtnImg.size.width*btn_count)/(btn_count+0x01));
    CGFloat width = _cancelBtnImg.size.width;

    if(x_displ < BTN_1ST_X)
    {
        x_displ = BTN_1ST_X;
        width = (alert_width - (BTN_1ST_X*0x02) - (BTN_GAP * (btn_count - 0x01))) / btn_count;
    }

    if(btn_count == 0x01)
    {
        x_displ = BTN_1ST_X;
        width = alert_width - (BTN_1ST_X*0x02);
    }

    UIButton  *_cancelBtn = nil;
    int       i          = 0x00;
    for(NSString *btn_title in buttonTitles)
    {
        _cancelBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_displ + (width + BTN_GAP)*i, alert_height, width, _cancelBtnImg.size.height)];
        [_cancelBtn setTag:BTN_TAG_BASE + i++];
        [_cancelBtn setTitle:btn_title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_cancelBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:20]];

        [_cancelBtn setBackgroundImage:_cancelBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [btn_array addObject:_cancelBtn];
    }

    if(i && _cancelBtn)
    {
        alert_height += _cancelBtn.frame.size.height + 15.0;
    }
}

//add background
_alertViewWithTable = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((int)   ((self.frame.size.width-alert_width)/2.0), (int)((self.frame.size.height-alert_height)/2.0 + 0x05), alert_width, alert_height)];
    _alertViewWithTable.autoresizingMask =     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    _alertImgView.frame = _alertViewWithTable.bounds;
    [_alertViewWithTable addSubview:_alertImgView];

    [self addSubview:_alertViewWithTable];

    if (_titleLbl)
         [_alertViewWithTable addSubview:_titleLbl];

if(_msgScrollView)
    [_alertViewWithTable addSubview:_msgScrollView];

if(_tableView)
    [_alertViewWithTable addSubview:_tableView];

for(UIButton *btn in btn_array)
    [_alertViewWithTable addSubview:btn];

return self;
}
- (id) initWithCaller:(id<MPAlertTableViewDelegate>)_caller title:(NSString*)_title
message:(NSString *)_messageString buttonTitles:(NSArray*)_buttonTitles
{
return [self initWithCaller:_caller title:_title message:_messageString tableDataSource:nil tableSelectedRowIndexs:nil buttonTitles:_buttonTitles];
}

- (id) initWithCaller:(id<MPAlertTableViewDelegate>)_caller title:    (NSString*)_title
  tableDataSource:(NSArray*)_tableDataArray
 tableSelectedRowIndexs:(NSArray*)_tableSelectedRowIndexs buttonTitles:(NSArray*)_buttonTitles
 {
     return [self initWithCaller:_caller title:_title message:nil      tableDataSource:_tableDataArray tableSelectedRowIndexs:_tableSelectedRowIndexs      buttonTitles:_buttonTitles];
 }

 - (void)showInView:(UIView*)view
 {
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
{
    [view addSubview:self];
    [self animateShow];
}
 }
 - (void)onBtnPressed:(id)sender
 {
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

int button_index = (int)button.tag-BTN_TAG_BASE;
 #ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"selected btn idx : %d", button_index);
 #endif   
          if (caller && [(NSObject *)caller respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedButtonIndex:withSelectedTableRowIndexArray:)])
     {
    NSMutableArray *selArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(tableSelectedRowIndexs)
    {
        NSArray *key_list = [tableSelectedRowIndexs allKeys];
        for(NSNumber *key in key_list)
        {
            BOOL yesNo = [[tableSelectedRowIndexs objectForKey:key] boolValue];
            if(yesNo)
                [selArray addObject:key];
        }
    }
    [caller didSelectedButtonIndex:button_index withSelectedTableRowIndexArray:selArray];
}
caller = nil;
[self animateHide];
}
 #pragma mark AlertTableView ShowHide relate code
 - (void)animateHide
 {
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
                                  animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];  
CATransform3D scale1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1);
CATransform3D scale2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1);
CATransform3D scale3 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 1);
NSArray *frameValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale1],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale2],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale3],
                        nil];
[animation setValues:frameValues];

NSArray *frameTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                       nil];
[animation setKeyTimes:frameTimes]
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.duration = 0.2;
[_alertViewWithTable.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"hide"];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:self afterDelay:0.105];
  }
 - (void)animateShow
{
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
                                  animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D scale1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1);
CATransform3D scale2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1);
CATransform3D scale3 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.9, 0.9, 1);
CATransform3D scale4 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1); 
NSArray *frameValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale1],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale2],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale3],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale4],
                        nil];
[animation setValues:frameValues];
NSArray *frameTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                       nil];
[animation setKeyTimes:frameTimes];
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.duration = 0.2;
[_alertViewWithTable.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"show"];
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
     #pragma mark UITableView relate code
 //- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    return MY_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
//}
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ABC"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"ABC"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;      
    // cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
}
if(data)
    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description];
else
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";   
if(tableSelectedRowIndexs)
{
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    if(tableSelectedRowIndexs && [[tableSelectedRowIndexs objectForKey:num] boolValue])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
 }
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(self.selectionType == ATV_SELECTION_TYPE_NORMAL)
{
    if (caller && [(NSObject *)caller respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedButtonIndex:withSelectedTableRowIndexArray:)])
    {
        NSArray *selArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
        [caller didSelectedButtonIndex:(-1) withSelectedTableRowIndexArray:selArray];
    }       
    caller = nil;
    [self animateHide];
    return;
}
else if(self.selectionType == ATV_SELECTION_TYPE_MULTI)
{
    // toggle value.
    if(tableSelectedRowIndexs)
    {
        NSNumber *num   = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
        BOOL checkOrNot = ![[tableSelectedRowIndexs objectForKey:num] boolValue];
        [tableSelectedRowIndexs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checkOrNot] forKey:num];
    }     
    if( cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone )
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    if(data && tableSelectedRowIndexs)
    {
        NSNumber *num   = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
        [tableSelectedRowIndexs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:num];
        int cnt = (int)[data count];
        for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        {
            NSNumber *reset_num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
            BOOL yesNo = [[tableSelectedRowIndexs objectForKey:reset_num] boolValue];
            if(yesNo && (i != indexPath.row))
            {
                [tableSelectedRowIndexs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE] forKey:reset_num];
                [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
 {
     return [data count];
 }
 @end
```

Comment: А можно перед [alert showInView:self.view]; поставить типа: NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame)); ?

Comment: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}} на 5s показал, похоже на правду

Comment: По-моему проблема вот тут:  UIImage *_alertBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert22.png"]; Картинка (которая в бэкграунде) не читается. Ширина ее 0. А дальше все вычисления frame идут  относительно  alert_width (скорей всего его ширина 40 пикселей - это то, что дается на отступ). Короче надо проверить наличие alert22.png и ее читабельность.

Comment: Да вы правы, косяк в том месте, я png переделал jpg и с работало, правда вот так https://yadi.sk/i/F7DKU_qsgnnmE ----вот  нада думать почему у png он границы не читает как нада!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему проблема вот тут:

```
UIImage *_alertBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert22.png"];
```

Картинка (которая в бэкграунде) не читается. Ширина ее 0. А дальше все вычисления frame идут относительно alert_width (скорей всего его ширина 40 пикселей - это то, что дается на отступ). Короче надо проверить наличие alert22.png и ее читабельность.

Что касается дефекта картинки. Надо в фотошопе ну или другом редакторе (я иногда пользуюсь http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net) сделать фон (вся область за рамкой) прозрачным и сохранить как png. Если это не поможет, то надо добавить строку вот тут:

```
[_alertViewWithTable addSubview:_alertImgView];
_alertViewWithTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Насчет фона и строки кода не помогло, я просто черный прямоугольник png вставляю и его даже не видет! _alertImgView.frame.size.width - эту величмну измеряю, когда jpg-290, как png то ноль, есть еще предположения?

Comment: Решило проблему удалением alert22@2x.png, в коде ограничение стояло на загрузку картинки по высоте.